# Resize table inside overflowing divs without JS

Tags: css, scroll, html-table, resize, overflow

Is it possible to resize columns in scrollable table when width of all columns has more pixels than div which contains table. The problem is I have something like 20 columns and I need to have my table scrollable with possibility of resizing columns. I successfully did it with JS mousemove, mouseup and mousedown events but I'm trying to do it with CSS it will cost user less resources. Example below:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll;max-height:300px;max-width:500px;background-color:gray;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
          <th style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
        <td>TESTTESTESTESTESTSTETSET</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, if this is what you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Table which can scroll and column will automatically resize</h2>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>bye</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Abc</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Arun</td>
      <td>Kumar</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did it ! Code of resizable column :
`<th>
<div style="resize:horizontal;overflow: auto;">TESTTESTESTEST</div></th>`

Comment: That's great! Do post if you find any difficulties executing the above code.